# sqlsrv_query doesn't return any result

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm sending to the MS SQL Server a long query with many actions:

```
$query = "
   DECLARE @ID_controllo INT;
   SELECT @ID_controllo= (SELECT isnull(max(ID),0)+1 FROM QCHECK_storico_controlli);
   INSERT INTO QCHECK_storico_controlli (...) VALUES (...);
   INSERT INTO QCHECK_storico_moduli (...) VALUES (...);
   INSERT INTO QCHECK_storico_moduli (...) VALUES (...);
   INSERT INTO QCHECK_storico_moduli (...) VALUES (...);
   SELECT @ID_controllo AS lastID;
";
```

All works and I find in the DB what I want but I thought to have "lastID" as result of `$result=sqlsrv_query($query)` function. Indeed I have no rows and I don't understand why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Since you're executing multiple queries, you need to use `sqlsrv_next_result()` to get the result of each. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php#123109

Comment: It would be simpler if you did the `SELECT` query in a separate call to `sqlsrv_query()`.

Comment: The row counts of the insert statements are probably confusing PDO. Have you tried adding `SET NOCOUNT ON; ` before your `DECLARE` line?